# Woocommerce: Add Price Suffix incl. Hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

is it possible to add a Hyperlink to the Price Suffix of WooCommerce?

To add a Suffix, I used this Code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
        $price = $price . 'zzgl. Versandkosten' ;
            return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

To Show the Text "zzgl. Versandkosten". I want to add a Hyperlink to "zzgl. Versandkosten" where Customers can read a PDF Documentation about our Shipping prices.

Thanks

Mauro

Comment: Wrap the suffix in an anchor tag?

Comment: I'm a rookie, so I dont know how this can be acomplished :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an anchor tag to the appended text like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
    $price = $price . '<a href="/">zzgl. Versandkosten</a>';
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

You can replace the '/' in the a tag with the URL you want to go to.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'www' (T_STRING) in /homepages/28/d683466602/htdocs/wp-content/themes/gecko/functions.php on line 29

EDIT:
 
GOT IT: It was " instead of '

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
 
    $price = $price . '<a href="http://www.xrel.to" target="_blank" >und zzgl. Versandkosten ';
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
  

}

Is there a possibility to underline the "zzgl. Versandkosten" String?

Comment: @MauroMorelli Best thing would be to give the anchor element a class and target it in CSS with 'text-decoration:underline;'. A quicker way would be to wrap the text in the anchor element in <em> (emphasis) like so:

`<a href="//:xrel.to" target="_blank"><em>zzgl. Versandkosten</em></a>`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
        $price = '<a href="link">' . $price . 'zzgl. Versandkosten </a>' ;
            return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```